# Solr Master/Slave synced docs shows different results in search

Tags: solr

i've got a very strange issue with solr in Master/Slave mode.

Solr 7.7.0 on all machines
1 Master with dataimporthandler from mssql
2 Slaves polling every 10seconds (same network)
2 million docs all are in sync
solrconfig.xml (except importhandler master from sql, slave from master) is the same
managed-schema is the same (as well all other like prot- stop- lang files)

If i do a search on the master for a name i've got a result of: 949

If i do exactly the same search on the slave i receive only a result of: 7

When i do search for one of the 949 ids directly by id on the slave i can see the "name" is present in that documents.

Thoughts about that?

Well, during posting i find out whats the difference is but don't know how to handle atm.

Query: "Guerreiro"

Master interprets "ue" as "u" and gives me 949 results.

Slave interprets "ue" as "ue" whats normally correct because Players Name is "Guerreiro" but here are only 7 results.

If i do a search on Slave as "Gurreiro" i received as well 949 results.

Debug query on master:

```
"explain":{
  "8893918-Event":"\n12.642701 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 486288) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  12.642701 = score(doc=486288,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.6689382 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      54.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1976687":"\n12.565664 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 19425) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  12.565664 = score(doc=19425,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.6587687 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      56.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "8893919-Event":"\n12.565664 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 507345) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  12.565664 = score(doc=507345,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.6587687 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      56.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "10276188-Event":"\n12.4143715 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 48138) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  12.4143715 = score(doc=48138,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.6387968 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      60.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "10276189-Event":"\n12.26668 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 48141) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  12.26668 = score(doc=48141,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.6193002 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      64.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "7864817-Event":"\n12.12246 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 6156) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  12.12246 = score(doc=6156,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.6002622 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      68.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1575843":"\n11.988101 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 87649) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.988101 = score(doc=87649,freq=4.0 = termFreq=4.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5825256 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      4.0 = termFreq=4.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      104.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1552933":"\n11.968596 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 65790) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.968596 = score(doc=65790,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5799509 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      40.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1503152":"\n11.865299 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 78430) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.865299 = score(doc=78430,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5663148 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      42.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1504127":"\n11.865299 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 80212) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.865299 = score(doc=80212,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5663148 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      42.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1159918":"\n11.865299 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 82475) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.865299 = score(doc=82475,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5663148 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      42.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "564037":"\n11.843961 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 57726) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.843961 = score(doc=57726,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.563498 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      76.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1580691":"\n11.782613 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 88413) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.782613 = score(doc=88413,freq=4.0 = termFreq=4.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5553995 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      4.0 = termFreq=4.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      112.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "8925627-Event":"\n11.763769 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 81400) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.763769 = score(doc=81400,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5529121 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      44.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "8925626-Event":"\n11.763769 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 355316) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.763769 = score(doc=355316,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5529121 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      44.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "10276195-Event":"\n11.763769 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 48095) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.763769 = score(doc=48095,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5529121 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      44.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "10606615-Event":"\n11.763769 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 6654) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.763769 = score(doc=6654,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5529121 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      44.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "8954014-Event":"\n11.7094555 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 225813) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.7094555 = score(doc=225813,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5457423 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      80.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1544175":"\n11.663963 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 65878) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.663963 = score(doc=65878,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5397369 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      46.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "8917783-Event":"\n11.663963 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 503828) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.663963 = score(doc=503828,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5397369 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      46.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "9061708-Event":"\n11.663963 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 511107) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.663963 = score(doc=511107,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5397369 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      46.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "10276196-Event":"\n11.663963 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 48140) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.663963 = score(doc=48140,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5397369 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      46.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "6508853-Event":"\n11.663963 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 20859) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.663963 = score(doc=20859,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5397369 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      46.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "10840594-Event":"\n11.577971 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 117079) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.577971 = score(doc=117079,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5283853 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      84.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "8954015-Event":"\n11.577971 = weight(OBJECT_Text:gurreiro in 166335) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  11.577971 = score(doc=166335,freq=3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n), product of:\n    7.5752964 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      1086.0 = docFreq\n      2118063.0 = docCount\n    1.5283853 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      3.0 = termFreq=3.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      74.24262 = avgFieldLength\n      84.0 = fieldLength\n"},
```

Debug on slave:

```
"explain":{
  "1719903":"\n14.679806 = weight(OBJECT_Text:guerreiro in 14420) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  14.679806 = score(doc=14420,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    12.550098 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      7.0 = docFreq\n      2115921.0 = docCount\n    1.1696965 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      73.88861 = avgFieldLength\n      120.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1719895":"\n14.679806 = weight(OBJECT_Text:guerreiro in 22428) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  14.679806 = score(doc=22428,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    12.550098 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      7.0 = docFreq\n      2115921.0 = docCount\n    1.1696965 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      73.88861 = avgFieldLength\n      120.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1719917":"\n6.2546177 = weight(OBJECT_Text:guerreiro in 22455) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  6.2546177 = score(doc=22455,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    12.550098 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      7.0 = docFreq\n      2115921.0 = docCount\n    0.498372 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      73.88861 = avgFieldLength\n      536.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1719927":"\n6.2546177 = weight(OBJECT_Text:guerreiro in 22470) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  6.2546177 = score(doc=22470,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    12.550098 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      7.0 = docFreq\n      2115921.0 = docCount\n    0.498372 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      73.88861 = avgFieldLength\n      536.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1719911":"\n5.74716 = weight(OBJECT_Text:guerreiro in 22445) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  5.74716 = score(doc=22445,freq=2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n), product of:\n    12.550098 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      7.0 = docFreq\n      2115921.0 = docCount\n    0.45793745 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      2.0 = termFreq=2.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      73.88861 = avgFieldLength\n      600.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1752793":"\n3.7844772 = weight(OBJECT_Text:guerreiro in 19629) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  3.7844772 = score(doc=19629,freq=10.0 = termFreq=10.0\n), product of:\n    12.550098 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      7.0 = docFreq\n      2115921.0 = docCount\n    0.3015496 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      10.0 = termFreq=10.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      73.88861 = avgFieldLength\n      5144.0 = fieldLength\n",
  "1752797":"\n3.7844772 = weight(OBJECT_Text:guerreiro in 19631) [SchemaSimilarity], result of:\n  3.7844772 = score(doc=19631,freq=10.0 = termFreq=10.0\n), product of:\n    12.550098 = idf, computed as log(1 + (docCount - docFreq + 0.5) / (docFreq + 0.5)) from:\n      7.0 = docFreq\n      2115921.0 = docCount\n    0.3015496 = tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:\n      10.0 = termFreq=10.0\n      1.2 = parameter k1\n      0.75 = parameter b\n      73.88861 = avgFieldLength\n      5144.0 = fieldLength\n"},
```

Comment: I would run the query with "debug=true" and compare the response that you get in the main vs one of the replicas. Look in the `explain` node that will come in the `debug` field of the response and see if there are any clues in there. I would also look at how the request was parsed, even though you said the solrconfig and schema are the same I would confirm that Solr is indeed parsing the request identically in all three nodes.

Comment: A missing schema sync could be the reason; also make sure that the total number of docs and index versions are the same. There might be underlying issues that cause the index to not be updated on the slaves (full diskspace, etc.)

Comment: @HectorCorrea, you are right there is a difference but how can i interpret this?

Slave has much less rows here in explain.

Comment: Update your question with the difference and see if that helps somebody spot the problem.

Comment: Your results make me suspect that definition of the `OBJECT_Text` field is different between the different servers. It looks like one is applying a different set of rules to handle "ue" different from the other. You could look at the definition that each server reports for this field and see if they are indeed different (e.g. `curl http://your-server-name/solr/your-core/schema/fields/OBJECT_Text`).

Comment: Hey @HectorCorrea, thanks, you pointed me to the right direction. Just a number was different here:  <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2" protected="protwords.txt"/> German2 and German had made this difference. Awesome. ty